# Placeholder glitch on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

#### Context:

I have an `<input>` element constructed as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field field-3">
    <span><input type="text" placeholder="Username" name=""></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**
*(with reset.css stylesheet written by Meyer in the same stylesheet)*

```
.field {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.field > span {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bbc3d3;
    float: right;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.field > span input[type="text"] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #9da3af;
    display: block;
    font-family: $font-open;
    @include font-size(12px);
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 0;
    resize: none;
    width: 838px;
    height: 22px;
}
```

#### The Glitch:

The input element placeholder shown as seen in the first image.
When I click inside the element and write something, the text moves one pixel down.

[image]

#### Where?:

The glitch only is displayed on Google Chrome

**The question:** How do I fix and avoid this from happening?

### Update

A [koala_web](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2049063/koala-dev) suggestion, use jsFiddle ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/ABLve/)) to exemplify.
**Note:** Ironically, in jsFiddle the problem does not play, but I put the link to the template example ([link](http://demo.sanntu.com/demo/demo.html)) where the glitch appears.

Comment: can you reproduce the behavior in a [fiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can test it?

Comment: @koala_dev, sample added links. Take a look please.
I want to hear your opinion. Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the line-height declaration from line 297 of your `style.css` file

```
html, body, button, input, select, textarea {
font-size: 12px;
/*line-height: 1.231; remove this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this glitch before and it does not seem like a big deal, however this is how I could deal with it. I would add a background image to the input box with the text center aligned in the center. Then apply it to the `<input>` css. When the user clicks on the input box make it so `background-image` is `none`. Like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #usernameInput{
        background-image: url(usernamePlaceholder.jpg);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="usernameInput" type="text" name="">
    <script>
        $('#usernameInput').click(function(){
            $('#usernameInput').css({
                'background-image' : 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ez2At/)

Comment: Look this!. I would never have thought this solution.
It's a solution, but not the solution I'm looking for.
I do not want to add an extra request to the server for a background image. In the example I cite a field, but in all the site I have N fields, and the possibility to exchange languages.
It is a good idea, but I expect that the solution be through css.
Thanks anyway!